# How do you create a yellow text box?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How do you create a yellow text box?

I tried the below but i cannot do it such that 
a) it does it in the active slide,
b) it is done yellow (potentially with some formatting as shadow)
thanks

```
Sub sticky()
Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
myDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=200, Height:=50).TextFrame _
.TextRange.Text = "Test Box"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1) instead of ActivePresentation.Slides(1) will generally give you the slide reference you need.

Try this for starters:

```
Sub sticky()
' Use object variables for slide and shape
Dim oSl as Slide
Dim oSh as Shape

' Get a reference to the current slide
Set oSl = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1)

' Add the shape and get a reference to it:
Set oSh = oSl.Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=200, Height:=50)

With oSh
  .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Test Box"
  .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
  ' Add any other formatting to the shape here 
End With  ' oSh ... the shape you added

End Sub
```